# Expand a div according to the amount of textbox

Tags: html, css, textbox, height

Does anyone knows how can I expand this div text box so the user can see the whole text or is there a way to put a functional scroll. I tried the last one but it does not works. I tried fit-content but it does not work:
[image]

the code is:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: code? goes  brrrrrrr

Comment: Sorry ...it is : <div class="emojionearea-editor" contenteditable="true" placeholder="" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"></div>

Answer (score 1):

Use `<textarea></textarea>` with style `overflow: auto; max-height: 4em; height: max-content; min-height: 2em;`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a little JS script:

```js
const tx = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
    tx[i].setAttribute("style", "height:" + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
    tx[i].addEventListener("input", onInput, false);
}

function onInput() {
    this.style.height = "auto";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
```

```css
textarea{
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

I assume that you use [this](https://mervick.github.io/emojionearea/) plugin. It is resizing bit at a specific amount of lines it goes into "scrollbar mode". I sadly didn't found a setting to disable the scrollmode.